# Using Into<String> on interfaces - zero cost for Vec<Into<String>>?

Tags: string, rust

I am using `Into<String>` as a parameter type to allow creating `Person`s with e.g. `str` as well as an owned `String`

```
pub struct Person {
    pub first_name: String,
    pub last_name: String,
}

impl Person {
    pub fn new<S>(first_name: S, last_name: S) -> Self
    where S: Into<String>
    {
        Self {
           first_name: first_name.into(),
           last_name: last_name.into(),
        }
    }
}
```

As far as a I know, due to monomorphism, this is zero cost at runtime.

Now, I am sure, this this is not zero cost:

```
pub struct Person {
    pub first_name: String,
    pub middle_names: Vec<String>,
    pub last_name: String,
}

impl Person {
    pub fn new<S>(first_name: S, middle_names: Vec<S>, last_name: S) -> Self
    where S: Into<String>
    {
        let middle_names: Vec<String> = middle_names.into_iter().map(|s| s.into()).collect();

        Self {
            first_name: first_name.into(),
            middle_names,
            last_name: last_name.into(),
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder if I can somehow make this going "zero cost". The `Vec` means that the data is on the heap, but maybe I can replace the `Vec` with some other useful data-structure or even a slice.

Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK, That depend of what is the real type of `S`, your function itself is zero cost, but his the user call you with `Vec<dyn Into<String>>` or similar well obviously this have a cost but not your function that the user who choice that.

Comment: @Stargateur "Zero-cost abstraction" in Rust is usually meant in the sense that the abstraction has no overhead over a fully manual implementation. The first implementation performs optimally for all of `String`, `&str` and `&dyn Into<String>` – implementing separate constructors for these cases would not improve performance. The second implementation, on the other hand, does not perform optimally for `String`, since it unnecessarily copies the vector.

Comment: @Stargateur Also note that `Vec<dyn Into<String>>` is not a valid type.

Comment: @Lichtbringer You probably could implement this with unsafe code, but it would be tricky and involved, so my suggestion would be to only accept `String` in the `new()` constructor, and provide a separate constructor for the generic case.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I don't agree, Rust compiler should see that `middle_names` is a noop. But optimisation is not sure. But I wasn't talking about the vector but just about the type inside. `middle_names` is not in the first implementation so the creation of the vector is not the sujet. So I didn't take it in account.

Comment: @Stargateur My interpretation of the question is that it is exactly about that overhead for allocating a new vector and copying the entries, but I'll let the OP clarify.

Comment: How about reserving some middle name space in the `Person` with, say, `middle_names: SmallVec<[String; 1]>`?

Comment: @SvenMarnach your interpretation aligns with my intent ;) so, yes: I would like to avoid the allocation and copying over if I already know that my `Vec<S>` is indeed a `Vec<String>`

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few solutions I can think of.

#### Implement two different constructors

You could implement two separate constructors – one for `S = String` and one for `S: Into<String>`. People will have to use different names for the two cases if they care about optimization.

#### Ignore the problem

I don't know about your actual use case, but this doesn't look like something that is likely to become a performance bottleneck for your application, so you could simply accept the tiny overhead. The string data itself won't be copied, only the metadata (a pointer, a length and a capacity), so the overhead is rather small.

#### Use specialization

Rust nightly partly support [specialization of traits](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md), so you can implement traits for overlapping sets of types. This allows you to implement a `IntoStringVec` trait with a specialization for `String` that does nothing

```
#![feature(specialization)]

trait IntoStringVec: Sized {
    fn into_string_vec(v: Vec<Self>) -> Vec<String>;
}

impl IntoStringVec for String {
    fn into_string_vec(v: Vec<String>) -> Vec<String> {
        v
    }
}

impl<T: Into<String>> IntoStringVec for T {
    default fn into_string_vec(v: Vec<Self>) -> Vec<String> {
        v.into_iter().map(Into::into).collect()
    }
}
```

This solution requires to use Rust nightly.

#### Use unsafe code for an in-place conversion

You can implement an in-place conversion of the vector for the case that `size_of::<S>() == size_of::<String>()` and `align_of::<S>() >= align_of::<String>()`. Doing this manually is a bit tricky to get right, so I'd recommend finding some crate that implements this, e.g. the [map_in_place crate](https://docs.rs/map_in_place/0.1.0/map_in_place/).

---

I would personally ignore the issue until it becomes an actual problem, and if it does, go with the first soltuion.